# Setting new-line rules in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, format

I want to make the format of my code (Java) look like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    System.out.println(i);
    System.out.println(i+1);
}
```

above is for code that have brackets.

For the code that have only one line:

```
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) System.out.println(i);
```

I can do the first one but moving the System.out.println(i); to the same line as 'for', I cannot find the place to set.

Thank you in advance.

[Addition] I mean how to setting in preference so that when I press [Ctrl + Shift + F] it will format as what I want. Sorry for my bad explanation.

Comment: Any reason you don't want to follow the conventional Java bracing? Aside from anything else, I would *strongly* advise against braceless single-statement loops. It's very easy to end up with bugs that way.

Comment: @JonSkeet I don't want to use conventional Java bracing because I am just addicted to the old style that I've used for a long time, feel shame. :(

Comment: @user3769649: Then I would strongly suggest you get over it. Think of anyone you'll be working with - why would you want to impose your non-Java habits on them? The sooner you adjust to Java bracing styles, the better. (I wouldn't recommend using the 8-character indent Sun suggests, mind you - I haven't seen that in widespread use.)

Comment: @JonSkeet I guess so. Thank you for your advice! I'll try to get over it.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be no option. Someone submitted it as request in 2005 but it was never implemented https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=104910

So your only option seems to be to enable the `//@formatter:on` (respectively `:off`) and do them around your `for` statements and format them manually. But this seems like too much work so I would just let Eclipse format it like it already does.

Comment: Thank you very much! It would be too much work, so I think I'll stick with the old.